# How to call a stored procedure from a function in AS400 SQL

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a stored procedure that converts numbers to words

```
NUMBER_TO_WORDS (NUMBER, WORDS)
```

And I try to create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONVERT_TO_WORDS (NUMBER CHAR (14)) RETURNS TABLE (NUMBER CHAR (14), WORDS CHAR (256)) RETURN
CALL NUMBER_TO_WORDS (NUMBER, WORDS)
```

so that you can make a call like this:

```
SELECT WORDS FROM TABLE CONVERT_TO_WORDS ('123456')
```

but this syntax is not accepted in version 5R6

Is there a way to do this in AS400?

Comment: v5r6? Isn't this a typo? The latest release of such a very old v5 was v5r4 (end of support in 2013)...

Comment: You're right Mark, it is V7R1M0. Sorry

Comment: You do have an ability to call SPs from UDFs. We need more details on thes SP and UDF. Does the SP return a result set or does it have an output parameter `WORDS`? If it's an output parameter, then why do you need a table UDF (returning a single row with 1 column every time) instead of a scalar one?

Comment: The procedure is a piece of RPG code generated by Genexus
And I want to have it available to call it in queries
to fill worksheets or whatever kind of outputs

I use it in my java webapps to print invoices after having it declared as:

`CREATE PROCEDURE  MYLIB/NUMBER_TO_WORDS (
   IN CHAR(14), OUT CHAR(256)) 
   SPECIFIC MYLIB/NUMBER_TO_WORDS     
   EXTERNAL NAME  MYLIB/NUMBER_TO_WORDS
   LANGUAGE RPG GENERAL`

Note: the real names are shorter and in spanish

Comment: And it is obviously a deterministic procedure, because a number has only one way to phrase it

Comment: Parameter style GENERAL is just for calling Java programs. When calling RPGLE, you should specify parameter style SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need a table UDF.
Here is an example of a scalar one presuming, that the SP is not declared as `MODIFIES SQL DATA`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_TO_WORDS (NUMBER CHAR (14))
RETURNS CHAR (256)
BEGIN
  DECLARE L_WORDS CHAR(256);
  CALL NUMBER_TO_WORDS (NUMBER, L_WORDS);
  RETURN L_WORDS;
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT NUMBER, CONVERT_TO_WORDS (NUMBER) AS WORDS
FROM (VALUES '12345', '67890') T (NUMBER)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. But as there is a library for test and another for production, shouldn't I prefix the name of it? I've done it but it tells me that it can't find the column or global variable MYLIB

Comment: If you need to qualify your objects explicitly, you must do it according to a naming (system or SQL) currently used in your tool. Refer to the [Naming conventions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=elements-naming-conventions) topic.

Comment: In the SELECT statement, I don't understand the role of T in this syntax. I also did not find it in the documentation. This syntax seems strange to me: in the place where a table should be referenced, is there a list of values (feeding?) some unknown function T in the place of its argument?
I'm posting this comment because I can't get it to work, after multiple attempts

Comment: This is a correlation name of `nested-table-expression` of [table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=clause-table-reference). [fullselect](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=queries-fullselect) there may have a form of `values-clause` as above. In other words it's a correlation name of an artificial table of one column an 2 rows of constants just for example to run the statement **as is**. If it doesn't work, then provide your exact statement you run and a full error message instead of just "can't get it work".

Comment: Mark, I've already done it, below in response to Mike's advices

Comment: It's not clear what have you done and what you get exactly. If you created a scalar UDF as in my answer, then why do you call it as a table UDF (db2 correctly complains, that there is no such a **table** function as you want to call) and not as a scalar one as in my answer?

Comment: It's just for the sake of testing. I don't declare a function as scalar, or do I? As I have said the function only provides the phrasing of a number and that can only be single, but I don´t know how the system interprets what I configure, I'm scarcely understanding this way too sophisticated and witty SQL contraption

Answer (score 0):

I've just found an answer here:

https://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/185704-combining-stored-procedure-select-statement-possible

Answer (score 0):

**This is my situation in the real case**

GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL is the procedure MYLIB/NUMBER_TO_WORDS
GX70OSCV/A_PALABR is the function  MYLIB/CONVERT_TO_WORDS

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL (   INOUT CHAR(14), INOUT CHAR(256))   NO SQL                              DETERMINISTIC   EXTERNAL NAME  GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL   LANGUAGE RPGLE GENERAL`
Se ha creado el procedimiento PNUMAPAL en GX70OSCV.

**Then in said library, the procedure exists:**
Opc  Objeto       Tipo        Atributo   Texto
PNUMAPAL    *PGM        RPGLE       Convertir nro a palabras

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GX70OSCV/A_PALABR (NUMERO CHAR (14))   RETURNS CHAR (256)                               BEGIN                                       DECLARE PALABRAS CHAR(256);    CALL GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL (NUMERO, PALABRAS);   RETURN PALABRAS;   END`
Se ha creado la función A_PALABR en GX70OSCV.

**Then also, the function exists:**
Opc  Objeto       Tipo        Atributo   Texto
A_PALABR    *SRVPGM     CLE         SQL FUNCTION A_PALABR

**But its usage is not allowed:**
`SELECT * FROM (GX70OSCV/A_PALABR('12345')) as T`
Símbolo ( no válido. Símbolos válidos: FULL LEFT CROSS INNER RIGHT E

**I wonder what is wrong with it?**

Comment: If it is now a scalar function (which I think you have changed it to) it needs to be in the SELECT clause, not the FROM clause.  You have it placed like a table function, but without the word TABLE.  Better:  SELECT GX70OSCV/A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1.

Comment: Thanks Mike for all your contributions, I've learned from them.  
  
I still can't get it to work, though.  
  
`SELECT GX70OSCV/A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`  
No se ha encontrado la columna o variable global GX70OSCV.  
  
`SELECT * FROM TABLE (GX70OSCV/A_PALABRAS('12345')) as T`  
A_PALABRAS en GX70OSCV de tipo *N no encontrado.

Comment: If you use sql naming, then it must be `SELECT GX70OSCV.A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`. If you use system naming, then either try the same (dot is allowed instead of slash starting from some PTF in V7.1) *or* try `SET CURRENT PATH = 'SYSTEM PATH,GX70OSCV'` first once in the current session and `SELECT A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1` afterwards (it will search the function in the list of libraries specified in CURRENT PATH) *or* ask your system administrator if it's expected, that `MYLIB/MYFUNC` for scalar UDFs leads to SQL0206 you get.

Comment: Appreciating your help, Mark, following your indications:  
  
`SELECT GX70OSCV.A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`  
A_PALABR en GX70OSCV de tipo *N no encontrado.  
  
`SET CURRENT PATH = 'SYSTEM PATH,GX70OSCV'`  
Se ha completado la sentencia SET PATH.  
  
`SELECT A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1`  
A_PALABR en *LIBL de tipo *N no encontrado.  

And we are just two  Genexus developers with no access to a skillful system administration

Comment: The message means, that there is no such function. Does the following query return a row from the session you try to call this function? `SELECT * FROM QSYS2/SYSROUTINES WHERE FUNCTION_TYPE = 'S' AND IN_PARMS = 1 AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'GX70OSCV' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'A_PALABR'`

Comment: SPECIFIC_SCHEMA: **GX70OSCV**  
SPECIFIC_NAME: **A_PALABR**  
ROUTINE_SCHEMA: **GX70OSCV**  
ROUTINE_NAME: **A_PALABR**  
ROUTINE_TYPE: **FUNCTION**  
ROUTINE_CREATED: **2021-08-25-18.09.18.013000**  
ROUTINE_DEFINER: **OVACAREZZA**  
ROUTINE_BODY: **SQL**  
EXTERNAL_NAME: **GX70OSCV/A_PALABR(A_PALABR_1)**  
EXTERNAL_LANGUAGE: **-**  
PARAMETER_STYLE: **-**  
IS_DETERMINISTIC: **NO**  
SQL_DATA_ACCESS: **READS**  
SQL_PATH: ***LIBL**

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help anymore in this case. This works on my test system, and I have no idea why it doesn't work in your case. You either don't do what you post here or you definitely need to talk to your system administrator...

Answer (score 0):

**I’m opening this new thread to put things neater**

GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL is the procedure MYLIB/NUMBER_TO_WORDS
GX70OSCV/A_PALABR is the function MYLIB/CONVERT_TO_WORDS

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL ( INOUT CHAR(14), INOUT CHAR(256)) DETERMINISTIC EXTERNAL NAME GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL LANGUAGE RPGLE SQL`
Se ha creado el procedimiento PNUMAPAL en GX70OSCV.

**Then in library GX70OSCV, the procedure exists:**
Opc Objeto Tipo Atributo Texto
PNUMAPAL *PGM RPGLE Convertir nro a palabras

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GX70OSCV/A_PALABR (NUMERO CHAR (14)) RETURNS CHAR (256)`
`BEGIN`
    `DECLARE PALABRAS CHAR(256);`
    `CALL GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL (NUMERO, PALABRAS);`
    `RETURN PALABRAS;`
`END`

Se ha creado la función A_PALABR en GX70OSCV.

**Then also, the function exists:**
Opc Objeto Tipo Atributo Texto
A_PALABR *SRVPGM CLE SQL FUNCTION A_PALABR

**Testing its usage:**
`SELECT GX70OSCV/A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`
No se ha encontrado la columna o variable global GX70OSCV.

**Checking its definition:**
`SELECT * FROM QSYS2/SYSROUTINES WHERE FUNCTION_TYPE = 'S' AND IN_PARMS = 1 AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'GX70OSCV' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'A_PALABR'`

SPECIFIC_SCHEMA: **GX70OSCV**
SPECIFIC_NAME: **A_PALABR**
ROUTINE_SCHEMA: **GX70OSCV**
ROUTINE_NAME: **A_PALABR**
ROUTINE_TYPE: **FUNCTION**
ROUTINE_CREATED: **2021-08-26-13.57.46.963000**
ROUTINE_DEFINER: **OVACAREZZA**
ROUTINE_BODY: **SQL**
EXTERNAL_NAME: **GX70OSCV/A_PALABR(A_PALABR_1)**
EXTERNAL_LANGUAGE: **-**
PARAMETER_STYLE: **-**
IS_DETERMINISTIC: **NO**
SQL_DATA_ACCESS: **READS**
SQL_PATH: **"QSYS","QSYS2","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","GX70OSCV"**

Comment: I don't know why, but it really doesn't accept a library name for scalar UDF with system naming even on my v7r4. The workaround is to **not** qualify the function, but use `SET CURRENT PATH = SYSTEM PATH,GX70OSCV` beforehand in the same session. Another last suggestion is to try `SELECT A_PALABR (CAST '12345' AS CHAR (14)) FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1`. Such a casting is not needed on recent db2 versions, but older versions treated VARCHAR and CHAR as different data type, and this is why your v7r1 may complain on absent function with an appropriate set of parameters.

Comment: Nice of you to be back Mark. New hopes to try, but I'm sorry to say they aren't running either  
  
`SET CURRENT PATH = SYSTEM PATH,GX70OSCV`  
Se ha completado la sentencia SET PATH.  
  
`SELECT A_PALABR('12345') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`  
A_PALABR en *LIBL de tipo *N no encontrado.   

`SELECT A_PALABR(CAST '12345' AS CHAR(14) )  
 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 `                          
Símbolo '12345' no válido. Símbolos válidos: ) ,.  
  
Our version seems worse than yours

Comment: Sorry, wrong expression. Should be: `A_PALABR (CAST ('1234' AS CHAR(14)))`.

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GX70OSCV/A_PALABR (NUMERO CHAR (14))
RETURNS CHAR (256) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN  DECLARE PALABRAS CHAR(256); CALL GX70OSCV/PNUMAPAL (NUMERO, PALABRAS);  RETURN PALABRAS; END`                                                            
Se ha creado la función A_PALABR en GX70OSCV.

`SELECT A_PALABR (CAST ('1234' AS CHAR(14))) FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1`
La consulta no puede ejecutarse.  Vea los mensajes de nivel inferior  
No está permitido modificar datos SQL. CPF503E error message.

Comment: This probably means, that your function was found, but it calls SP defined as MODIFIES SQL DATA (yo may check it with QSYS2.SYSROUTINES) which is not allowed in DB2 for IMB i. You must redefine your SP as READS SQL DATA if it's possible to allow its call from a scalar UDF.

Comment: Finally and disappointingly the error messages were fixed adding the clause READS SQL DATA to the CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE. But the result was a simple dash character, although the SP continues to produce the correct output when called programmatically

Answer (score -1):

While you cannot call a User Defined Table Function directly in a `FROM` clause, there are other ways to work them into `SELECT` statements, three of which are shown here:

```
SELECT MyUDTF('input') as Result
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
-- here the IBM blank or dummy table is a placeholder just so that
-- the FROM clause is syntactically correct



SELECT *
FROM TABLE (MyUDTF('input')) AS T
-- Here you can get it into a subsection of the FROM clause and
-- get rid of the dummy table.
-- Note that this will not work without the extra parentheses
-- and explicitly declaring a table name.



SELECT *
FROM MyTable
JOIN TABLE (MyUDTF(MyTable.Field1, MyTable.Key)) AS T ON T.KEY = MyTable.Key
WHERE MyTable.Field2 = 'criteria'                                       
-- This one requires that your table function returns one of its
-- columns that can be correlated with the input.
-- This well worth designing in if you are going to use this on multiple records.
```

Comment: If I qualify the function in
`SELECT MYLIB/CONVERT_TO_WORDS('12345') AS RESULT FROM  sysibm.sysdummy1`
it tells me something like 'The column or global variable MYLIB was not found'. Although the function is in said library. Why is it so?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE (MYLIB/CONVERT_TO_WORDS('12345')) AS T`

displays the message: CONVERT_TO_WORDS IN MYLIB OF TYPE *N  NOT FOUND
But CONVERT_TO_WORDS exists in MYLIB  and returns CHAR(256), IDK what happens here

Comment: It sounds like this is the same not found error either way you call it. You need to confirm that both the SQL function exists in the Schema (created by calling `CREATE FUNCTION`, I would use System i Navigator to verify its existence) and that the *PGM object exists in the library (Created by `CRTRPGBND`, I would use `WRKPGM` or `DSPLIB` to confirm it exists).  You should also make sure that the SQL function is trying to call the *PGM object that you expect.  Also `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` is useful here if you have to make adjustments and rebuild this to get it to work.